# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' error in discord.py in python

Tags: python, discord.py

I had made a bot for discord in python

```
import discord,requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
import os
from discord.ext import *
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

@client.command()                                       #=====================Hello
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello @{ctx.author}")

client.run(os.getenv["TOKEN"])
```

I have given the token in my `.env` file for my server security

When I am trying to run it it gives me the error below.

```
     $ "C:/Program Files/Python37/python.exe" "d:/Code/python projects/Arsenal_ Discord_bot/Bot.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Code/python projects/Arsenal_ Discord_bot/Bot.py", line 211, in <module>        
    client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run   
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: `os.getenv["TOKEN"]` → `os.getenv("TOKEN")`

Comment: it gives me another error

Comment: i update my question to show my error

Comment: To use a `.env` file you need a package such as `python-dotenv`, otherwise Python has no way of knowing that you want it to read this file and add the values to the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only to the completeness that an answer can be accepted and help other users with similar problems - the question was answered in the comments :D

"To use a `.env` file you need a package such as `python-dotenv`, otherwise Python has no way of knowing that you want it to read this file and add the values ​​to the environment"